# How can I transform a code that split '|' into a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I have a column called brands. The rows look like this

```
 |Brands|

|Gucci|Prada|
|Versace|Levis|Adidas|
|Champion|Diesel|Nike|
```

I have a code to split the '|' from the column brands.

```
split_columns=['Brands']

for brand in split_brands:
    brands_data[brand]=brands_data[brand].apply(lambda x: x.split('|'))
```

That code work well and split the '|'.

My question is :

How I can transform that code into a function. I would like to learn to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
def func(split_brands):
    for brand in split_brands:
        brands_data[brand]=brands_data[brand].apply(lambda x: x.split('|'))
```

Answer (score 0):

**I will use [Google Doc String Format](https://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_google.html) and convert your code. The important thing is to name your function and arguments something intelligible so that they can be understood and interpreted easily**

---

```py
def split_columns(brands, brands_data):
    """Used to split column string on the `|` character

    Args:
        brands (str): String containing brand names separated
            by `|` character to be seperated
        brands_data (pandas df column): Dataframe column containing the information

    Returns:
        The updated dataframe column
    """    

    for brand in brands:
        brands_data[brand]=brands_data[brand].apply(lambda x: x.split('|'))

    return brands_data
```

---

**That being said I feel like something feels off here.**

If you are simply passing in a column and all you want to do is get the column back out such that each entry is now a nested list... 
**`'1|Versace|Levis|Adidas|' --> ['1','Versace','Levis','Adidas']`**

The easiest way would be to not use a function and simply call **`.apply()`** directly:

---

*Assuming a dataframe named **`df`** and a dataframe row named **`Brands`***

```py
>>>df
                    Brands
0           0|Gucci|Prada|
1  1|Versace|Levis|Adidas|
2  2|Champion|Diesel|Nike|

>>>df["Brands"] = df["Brands"].apply(lambda row: row.split('|'))
>>>df
                          Brands
0            [0, Gucci, Prada, ]
1  [1, Versace, Levis, Adidas, ]
2  [2, Champion, Diesel, Nike, ]
```

**Hopefully this clarification may help you**

Comment: I think the thing that I was missing is that i forgot to write an equal here : split columns=['Brands']

Comment: That makes sense. If my answer helped or you think it will help others please make sure to click the check. If not feel free to answer your question yourself and then select it so people know where to look for the answer. :)

Comment: I have a question, Im getting an Attribute Error. "float"object has no attribute "split".              Here:  brands_data[brand]=brands_data[brand].apply(lambda x: x.split('|')) . What could I do in this case?

Comment: This is because somewhere in brands_data there is a **`brads_data[brand]`** that is a float (number with decimals). Try printing out all your **`brands_data[brand]`** and look for something that isn't a string (doesn't look like "0|Gucci|Prada|" or something similar). As a quick workaround you could change your code to this... but again it feels weird... ---> **`brands_data[brand]=brands_data[brand].apply(lambda x: str(x).split('|'))`** This is simply forcing the type to string prior to running the split command. It's a bandaid but it should fix the error. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank so much!! Your solution solved the problem. A gold medal for you!